# What is なのは used in this sentence?

Tags: formal-nouns, na-adjectives

What is the なのは used in "なかでも にんき なのは ポケモンどうしを たたかわせて".

I know にんき is a na-adjective but i don't understand the use of なのは.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`の` is a noun with general reference. The na-adjective attributively modifies it. `は` is the topic marker. So you get `人気なのは` "as for the thing that is popular".