# Na-adjectives before は

Tags: grammar, particle-は, na-adjectives

Do na-adjectives need a な before a は?

> もっと きれいなは どうですか。
>
> もっと きれいは どうですか。

Which is correct?

Personally I think な is needed as the sentence is a shorter form of もっと きれいな ハンドバッグは どうですか。(replace ハンドバッグ with any noun). References say to use な in front of modified nouns, but nothing about は particles. I have tried Googling for もっと (na-adj)なは but I am still not sure.

Comment: You need to nominalize the na-adjective きれい by appending の: もっときれいな**の**はどうですか。. See also: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4795/, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19514/.

Comment: I think some linguists would suggest distinguishing pronomial の from nominalizing の.  See *A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar* (Makino & Tsutsui) p.315.

Comment: @senshin I see. So the bottom one would be preferable, then?

Comment: @rhyaeris Neither of your two proposed sentences is grammatical, and I don't think either one sounds "less ungrammatical" than the other.

Answer (score 3):

(The question was answered in the comment section; therefore, I will community-wiki this.)

> もっと きれいなは どうですか。
>
> もっと きれいは どうですか。
>
> Which is correct?

Neither is, unfortunately.

The correct sentence that is shortest and most natural would be:

> 「もっときれいな**の**はどうですか。」 ("How about a prettier ***one***?")

This is because you cannot attach a 「は」 to an adjective without nominalizing the adjective first.

Also correct but somewhat colloquial/slangy would be:

> 「もっときれいな**やつ**はどうですか。」

Not that I recommend that you use 「やつ」 actively, but you will see/hear it quite often.